# Using emoji-picker package in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement an emoji picker for an input box. It's my first time with it and I'm having a problem while using. I could't give the user the ability to type more than one emoji. The emoji selected before always substitutes the previous one. can someone help me with that? for now I decided to test it in a sandbox, but if I'm able to pull it out, I'll use it in a project. Here's the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Picker, { SKIN_TONE_MEDIUM_DARK } from "emoji-picker-react";

const App = () => {

  const [emoji, setEmoji] = useState([])

  const onEmojiClick = (event, emojiObject) => {
    setEmoji(emojiObject);
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <Picker onEmojiClick={onEmojiClick} skinTone={SKIN_TONE_MEDIUM_DARK} />

      <input
        type="text"
        id="input"
        onChange={e => setEmoji([...emoji, e.target.value])}
        value={emoji.emoji}
      />

    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

that's because you are overwriting the state of emojis. maybe you could store them in an array and do this:

`setUseEmoji([...useEmoji, newEmoji])`

then map over them when you want to display them

`useEmoji.map((emoji) => <div> {emoji} </div>)`

Comment: I couldn't do it, I'm going to edit my question and show you my changes, but I'm getting the same error: 'Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance'

Comment: @GabrielTisoVinhasdeBrito check my new answer

Answer (score 0):

set this to be an array from the start

from: `const [emoji, setEmoji] = useState({})`

to: `const [emoji, setEmoji] = useState([])`

then set it like this: `setEmoji([...emoji, e.target.value])`

then iterate over it like so:

`emoji.map((emj) => <div> {emj} </div>)` or if it's an object:

`emoji.map((emj) => <div> {emj.propertyValue} </div>)`

Comment: o, but I'll sue the setUseEmoji([...emoji, e.target.value]) in my handleChange or in my handleSubmit?

Comment: sorry don't use `setUseEmoji` use this: `setEmoji([...emoji, e.target.value])` inside `handleChange`

Comment: I'll edit the question again. It's not working. Have a look

Comment: when you say "it's not working" which part? you aren't doing this `emoji.map((emj) => <div> {emj.emoji} </div>)` so it's not going to show more than one

Comment: and you haven't changed this: `setEmoji(emojiObject);` to `setEmoji([...emoji, emojiObject])`

Comment: I don't want to map the emojis, I want the user to have the ability to type multiple emojis in the input box

Comment: And every time i console.log the emoji array, the 7newest emoji always overrides the previous one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215586/discussion-between-gabriel-tiso-vinhas-de-brito-and-red-baron).

Answer (score 0):

This will happen because you need to add other emojis and keep the old one as it is. but you are replacing the previous one with a new one. To achieve your task, you need to push the new emojis into the array and for that, the easiest way is to modify your function to:

```
const onEmojiClick = (event, emojiObject) => {setEmoji([...emojiObject,emojiObject.emoji]);};
```